# Change/update a variable in Handlebars JS from the parent context inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I've seen many examples of how to *access* a variable which belongs to the parent context inside a loop. However, I need to not only access the variable but change/update it as well.

As you can see below, I have a custom helper that sets a variable, but I when try to change that variable inside the loop, it does not work. Is there a way to make it work?

Please take a look at this **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jerzx0sn/2/)**.

**Template**

```
{{setVarWithName "test" "hello"}}
{{#each questions}}
    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
    <p>before update: {{../test}}</p>
    {{setVarWithName "test" "goodbye"}}
    <p>after update: {{../test}}</p>
    <hr />
{{/each}}
```

**Handlebars init with helper**

```
var source = $("#template").html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 

var data = {
  "questions": [
     {"title": "Question 1"},
     {"title": "Question 2"}
   ]
}; 

Handlebars.registerHelper('setVarWithName', function (name, value) {
    this[name] = value;
    return '';
});

$('body').append(template(data));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, like often in JavaScript, is the scope. Basically, `this` inside of your helper `setVarWithName` does not point into your `data` variable when used inside of `{{#each}}` loop, but it does point into the `question[@index]`. What you need to do:

```
var source = $("#template").html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 

var data = {
  "questions": [
     {"title": "Question 1"},
     {"title": "Question 2"}
   ]
}; 

Handlebars.registerHelper('setVarWithName', function (name, value) {
    data[name] = value; // changed from this to data
    return '';
});

$('body').append(template(data));
```

See my working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eskse98n/1/). I added `{{s}}` helper to print rendered `this` into the template for readability.